# laravel set postgresql identity column in migration

Tags: laravel, postgresql, migration

laravel `$table->id()` will set default `nextval('tablename_id_seq'::regclass)`

how to set **GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY**

```
CREATE TABLE color (
    color_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    color_name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote from the index modifiers table in [the current documentation regarding migrations:](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations)

| `->generatedAs($expression)` | Create an identity column with specified sequence options (PostgreSQL). |
| --- | --- |

The following code

```php
Schema::create('color', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->mediumInteger('color_id')->generatedAs();
    $table->string('color_name');
});
```

generates

```sql
create table "color" (
  "color_id" integer generated by default as identity not null,
  "color_name" varchar(255) not null
)
```

If you add `->nullable()` between `mediumInteger('color_id')` and `generatedAs()`, the color_id column is instead:

```
"color_id" integer generated by default as identity null
```